# “Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzata]

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate the firebase perf in Android. Below are my dependencies.When i tried to run the build, it gives me error "Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzata] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes)"

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
#############
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0'
```

Comment: I think you should remove `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1"`, as it has included the dependencies below(ads-auth-gcm)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by mixing

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1"`

With the rest of your 15.0.0 and up dependencies. This is causing duplicate definitions of certain symbols in the libraries, which manifests itself in many ways, in this instance by saying it can't find the super class of a particular obfuscated class, because it is likely the sub-class and super class come from conflicting definitions of a library.

1.) `play-services:12.0.1` is an alias target, which will pull in the 12.0.1 version of all `play-services-*` and `firebase-*` libraries, likely not what you want.

2.) Only Google Play services library versions after 15.0.0 can have different versions.  See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you are lacking `play-services-base` (which is that `super class` for the others):

```
// implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply. It is still giving the same error.  sometimes, it might need to do with progaurd, guessing.

Comment: @ketanmuttha, did you try this suggestion by also commenting out implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1" as suggested?

You shouldn't need to explicitly include play-services-base since the other libraries listed should have a POM-level dependency onto play-services-base, automatically pulling in the right dependent version.

Comment: @zfromg think this isn't the case anymore, since the new versioning.... while the dependency to the library at version `12.0.1` has to be removed (which still adds a whole bunch of further dependencies).

Comment: @ketanmuttha try to clean the project or delete the `build` directory; because there still may be conflicting files present in the build-cache.